# Problem with installing GNU make in Python27

Tags: python

I got an error message saying that

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement make-3.82 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for make-3.82
```

I'm using the Python27 environment and tried with GNU make-3.79 to all newer libraries up to GNU make-3.42 by downloading from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/, but the same problem repeating for all version.

```
$ pip install make-3.79
```

My final gall is to install library "elevation" with all dependencies of
GNU maker, curl, unzip, gunzip in python27.

Comment: Why are you trying to install `make` with `pip`? GNU make is not a python package.

Comment: @melpomene, thank you very much for your attention. I wanted to install "elevation" to download SRTM dem

Comment: [The end of python 2.7 ist near.](https://pythonclock.org/). So please stop using it.

Comment: Try `pip install make` https://pypi.org/project/make/

Comment: @finswimmer, thank you, but I'm using geopandas library so It's less problematic in Pyrhon 2.7

Comment: @Codelt, thank you. I  tried but I received a similar error ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement make (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for make